# How do I list my Heroku apps along with their domain names?

Tags: heroku

Seems like a pretty standard thing to want to do, but I can’t find any easy way of doing it?

Comment: how do you want to do it this question is too open ended

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In zsh, you can try something like this:

```
for site (`heroku list`); do echo `heroku domains --app $site`; done;
```

which will dump out the info for each app.  It's not pretty, but it's a start.

Comment: Thanks, this is pretty good (I upvoted it), but I also just discovered that the Heroku API can actually provide all the apps and domain names in a single request, so I’m trying to cook something up myself right now. :D

Comment: Have tweaked my answer to give a better output

Comment: OK, I submitted a patch: https://github.com/heroku/heroku/pull/278 Accepting your answer as a decent workaround. Thanks again!

Comment: You'll need tests to get that accepted.  Also, what if an app has many domains?

Comment: I believe ```heroku apps --json``` will also produce the result you desire. Look for the 'web_url' key.

Answer (score 22):

Just type `heroku apps` on the computer's command line that you have ssh keys for the heroku.
For further info [click here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-the-cli).

Answer (score 5):

Here's a command line solution using `jq` and the `--json` flag:

```
heroku apps -A --json | jq '.[] | .["web_url"]'
```

Answer (score 3):

from your app folder run `heroku domains` (--app name eventually)

```
 heroku domains
 Domain names for xxxx.herokuapp.com:
 aa.example.com
 bbb.example.com
```

Comment: Yeah... but then I have to first clone every app I have and run that command on each one individually.

Answer (score 3):

**Method 1 :**

In shell, you can execute this script to list app-name and domains.

```
apps=( `heroku apps` )
echo "Total number of apps :"  $(( ${#apps[@]} -3 )) 
for (( i = 3 ; i < ${#apps[@]} ; i++ ))
do
    echo $(( i-2)) ] `heroku domains --app  ${apps[$i]}`
done
```

**Method 2:**

You can use Heroku API

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-quickstart#calling-the-api

Comment: This is the tool agnostic way to do this that I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this command to list all the Heroku apps and respective domain names with Bash:

```
heroku apps | awk '{print $1;}' | sed 's/[^a-zA-Z0-9-]//g' | sed  '/^$/d' | while read line ; do echo "$line" ; heroku domains --app $line | grep 'herokuapp\|herokudns\|herokussl' ; done
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed to figure out what heroku app was using the domain I wanted to reuse.  Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Go to: https://api.heroku.com/myapps

That lists all your apps that have been pushed up.
Click on each one individually and it will tell you the domain name.

Comment: The problem is the "click on each one individually" part. :-)